# Unfortunately stopped

Tags: android

I am facing a strange problem in my app. Sometimes an error Message comes as "**Unfortunatly stopped**" and I have to restart the app. It sudddenly occurs sometimes. I require help on two issues
1. What are the reasons why "unfortunately stopped" error occurs
2. Can we trap this error (I have put Try block, but it does not go there) and prevent the application from crashing
I suspect is related to performance issues, but not sure.

Comment: Some code or logcat output would be useful to help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Grab a logcat just after the crash. You can do this in one of the following ways:

- If you launch your app from Eclipse, it will show you a Logcat window.
- Or issue `adb logcat` from the command line. (Assuming adb is in your PATH).
- Or get a logcat app, such as aLogcat (https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.jtb.alogcat).

The logcat will tell you the exception class that was thrown, any associated error message and the line in your code that caused the exception. If you need help analyzing the logcat, post it here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. This error does not occur in eclipse but after I load the apk file to my tablet, this issue appears but at indefinite intervals. i.e., which works fine also gives error after some time

Comment: Then you will need a logcat app (see above). Fire it up right after your app crashes and save your logcat to a file, then look for unhandled exceptions.